# O futuro do pretérito não é mais empregado em Portugal?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu

Tanto na língua informal como na formal usada em Portugal, não mais percebe-se o uso do futuro do pretérito, que, em inglês, teria seu similar no tempo passado de will: would.

Um exemplo recente que vi na TV portuguesa: um jornalista, de modo a evitar empregar o futuro do pretérito, fez a seguinte construção:

"Matou a esposa em Santarém. Terá sido por ciúmes." O que achei insólito.

Creio que isso dificulte o aprendizado do idioma por aqueles que falam a língua inglesa, que, por usarem cotidianamente o would, entendem de imediato o sentido desse tempo quando ensinados. Já o 'terá sido' não possui tradução possível no inglês sem passar pelo equivalente deles ao nosso futuro do pretérito: would.

Ou seja, sem o futuro do pretérito essa tarefa fica muito mais difícil para eles:

"Gostava de viajar" -- já nao gosta mais, pois hoje está velho e cansado.
"Gostava de viajar" -- mal pode esperar para as próximas férias.

Como um português consegue ser entendido por outro no caso acima? Ignora-se sempre o primeiro caso? O pretérito imperfeito sempre será interpretado como sendo um tempo futuro?

Comment: A pergunta parece-me um bocado confusa. Que tem o futuro perfeito de _terá sido por ciúmes_, que exprime incerteza, que ver com o futuro do pretérito?

Comment: @Artefacto, as manchetes jornalísticas do Brasil fazem-se (normalmente) da seguinte forma "teria sido por ciúmes".

Comment: @Artefacto A pergunta/título "O futuro do pretérito não é mais empregado em Portugal?" foi amparada por um exemplo de um jornalista fazendo uso do futuro perfeito para citar um evento passado, de modo a evitar o uso do futuro do pretérito. Não há qualquer problema de coesão textual.

Comment: @JoãoMatias esse uso do futuro perfeito não é feito para evitar o futuro do pretérito. Quando muito é feito para evitar o pretérito perfeito: _foi por ciúmes_. A diferença entre os dois é modal, não temporal. Compara, no presente, no sentido habitual: _ele grita com a esposa?_ vs _Gritará ele com a esposa?_ (ou _será que...)_. O futuro do pretérito seria _Matou a esposa. Seria por ciúmes_, o que não encaixa (seria necessário um ponto de referência no passado: _todas as noites ele gritava com a esposa. Fá-lo-ia por ciúmes_)

Comment: @ErgativeMan bom, estou a ver. Mas nesse exemplo particular a escolha é entre dois tempos compostos e não entre o futuro do pretérito simples e outro tempo. Em Portugal, _teria sido por ciúmes_ também me parece possível, mas seria mais usado com referência anterior: _Ele tinha matado a esposa. Teria sido por ciúmes_.

Comment: Você deveria dar exemplos com frases completas. por favor. Porque agora eu precisou imaginar o que você quer dizer.

Comment: Eu gostaria de viajar. I would like to travel. would is modal here, not the pass tense of will. Eu não imagino possível o não uso do futuro do pretérito em português. Se usa muito.

Answer (score 3):

Não exatamente, usa-se o "pretérito perfeito", que podemos chamar também de *condicional*, às vezes. Ao fazer pedidos, é comum o uso do pretérito imperfeito do indicativo, até no Brasil:

> "Queria viajar."

Chama-se esta utilização um *valor modal* do pretérito imperfeito. Em Portugal (e até no Brasil já o vi) é comum usar para coisas hipotéticas o futuro do indicativo com este valor modal mais de hipótese.

No português europeu o condicional é usado, assim como no Brasil, em questões nas quais há de fato uma condição: "se X, então Y" ou quando se trata literalmente de um futuro possível do passado.

Mas, sim, o uso é reduzido na variedade europeia, só ainda não 100% ausente.

Estas diferenças relativas a tempo, modo, aspecto e todas as formas de construí-los, com flexões, afixos, verbos auxiliares etc são naturais entre todas as línguas, é natural que um falante de inglês encontre dificuldades ao aprender português e vice-versa. Pense em quantos falantes de outras línguas sofrem com as cadeias de verbos auxiliares do inglês:

> *It would have been possible if...*

Quanto às duas possibilidades de frases que deu, é outra coisa que toda língua possui: ambigüidades. Estas são quase sempre desfeitas pelo contexto — é a magia da pragmática — e, neste caso, raramente geram confusão, além da clássica piada que todo falante que qualquer falante de português já ouviu:

> "Queria férias"/"Gostava de férias"

> "Ah, então não quer mais?"/"então não gosta mais?"

Aliás, no Brasil usa-se também uma construção de hipótese como o futuro:

> Será que ele foi ao mercado?

Comment: Bons pontos! Mas o que me chama a atenção é que se eu escrevesse "terá" para me referir a algo passado em alguma redação na escola ou universidade, teria sido repreendido pelos professores. "Foi por ciúmes, é uma das possibilidades segundo a PJ" ou "Pode ter sido por ciúmes", parece mais correto do que usar o "terá" para se referir a um evento ocorrido. "Terá gostado do show dos Pearl Jam ontem?" soa bem aos ouvidos portugueses? E se o futuro do pretérito é usado para "indicar algo que pode ocorrer posteriormente a um determinado fato passado", poderia ter sido usado sem qualquer problema.

Comment: Essas coisas também tornam o inglês mais difícil para portugueses, pois no PT-BR fazemos a tradução natural: "Eu gostaria de viajar"/"I'd like to travel", já no PT-PT o "I'd like to travel" seria traduzido naturalmente como "I liked to travel", o que é incorreto. O não uso do gerúndio também dificulta: PT-BR: "I'm eating" se torna naturalmente "Estou comendo", em PT-PT: "I'm eating" se torna "I am to eat" (forma incorreta de "estou a comer"). Embora em Portugal se veja o futuro do pretérito como um tempo verbal brasileiro, e o gerúndio como uma forma nominal brasileira, isso não é verdade.

Comment: Em Portugal normalmente se usa aquilo que adicionei à resposta agora, igual ao Brasil: "será que...". Novamente, este futuro não tem valor temporal, apenas modal de dúvida, não é um futuro de fato, é um "levantador de hipótese".

Comment: Quanto à dificuldade de aprender inglês, tenho as minhas dúvidas, especialmente quanto à forma condicional, é um sistema totalmente diferente de ambas as formas. Também em relação à última parte, não acredito que se tenha o condicional como uma "forma brasileira". Já o gerúndio *em construções progressivas* é mais associado ao Brasil, apesar de que em lugares no sul de Portugal seja usado em tais construções também. Mas, é claro, o gerúndio é usado em Portugal, no geral, em outros casos, assim como a + infinitivo também o é em outros casos no Brasil.